Translate JSON data into ORACLE sql table
```
select
  JT.*
FROM
        JSON_TABLE (json_sample)
 '$.general[*]'
            COLUMNS (
                product_key NUMBER PATH '$.product_key',
                group_subtype_id NUMBER PATH '$.group_subtype_id',
                group_subtype_name VARCHAR2 ( 100 ) PATH '$.group_subtype_name',
                variant_id NUMBER PATH '$.variant_id',
                variant_name VARCHAR2 ( 100 ) PATH '$.variant_name',
                rb_customer_id NUMBER PATH '$.rb_customer_id',
                NESTED PATH '$.partnumbers[*]'
                    COLUMNS (
                        partnumber VARCHAR2 ( 100 ) PATH '$.partnumber',
                        pn_type VARCHAR2 ( 100 ) PATH '$.pn_type',
                        mat_status VARCHAR2 ( 100 ) PATH '$.mat_status',
                        base_wire_esd VARCHAR2 ( 10 ) PATH '$.properties[0].value',
                        pressure VARCHAR2 ( 10 ) PATH '$.properties[1].value',
                        NESTED PATH '$.document_numbers[*]'
                            COLUMNS (
                                document_number VARCHAR2 ( 100 ) PATH '$.document_number',
                                document_verion NUMBER PATH '$.document_verion',
                                document_type VARCHAR2 ( 100 ) PATH '$.document_type',
                                NESTED PATH '$.target_markets[*]'
                                    COLUMNS (
                                        country_name VARCHAR2 ( 100 ) PATH '$.country_name',
                                        iso_code VARCHAR2 ( 10 ) PATH '$.iso_code',
                                        NESTED PATH '$.hierarchy_information[*]'
                                            COLUMNS (
                                                child_product NUMBER PATH '$'
                                            )
                                    )
                            )
                    )
            )
        )
    jt
```

Sample JSON:

'''    {
"general": {
"product_key": "136587",
"group_subtype_id": 1,
"group_subtype_name": "Wheel Speed Sensor",
"variant_id": 2,
"variant_name": "DF11",
"rb_customer_id": 16732
},
"partnumbers": [
{
"partnumber": "0265009953",
"pn_type": "Series OEM",
"mat_status": "40 - Valid",
"properties": [
{
"property_id": 4,
"property_name": "ASIC P/N",
"value_id": 27,
"value": "8905509055"
},
{
"property_id": 5,
"property_name": "ASIC type",
"value_id": 56,
"value": "TLE4942"
},
{
"property_id": 6,
"property_name": "Axle",
"value_id": 64,
"value": "Front"
},
{
"property_id": 7,
"property_name": "Base Type - Development P/N",
"value_id": null,
"value": null
},
{
"property_id": 8,
"property_name": "Base Type - Released P/N",
"value_id": 73,
"value": "F00C1B0037"
},
{
"property_id": 9,
"property_name": "Bracket assembly @ Bosch",
"value_id": null,
"value": null
},
{
"property_id": 10,
"property_name": "Bulk cable P/N",
"value_id": null,
"value": null
},
{
"property_id": 11,
"property_name": "Cable assembly P/N1",
"value_id": null,
"value": null
},
{
"property_id": 12,
"property_name": "Cable assembly P/N2",
"value_id": null,
"value": null
},
{
"property_id": 13,
"property_name": "Cable assembly P/N3",
"value_id": null,
"value": null
},
{
"property_id": 14,
"property_name": "Cable Length in mm",
"value_id": null,
"value": null
},
{
"property_id": 15,
"property_name": "Cable/Connector Outlet in Deg",
"value_id": 110,
"value": "Axial"
},
{
"property_id": 16,
"property_name": "Character",
"value_id": 136,
"value": "Crimped"
},
{
"property_id": 17,
"property_name": "Clip assembly Bosch",
"value_id": null,
"value": null
},
{
"property_id": 18,
"property_name": "Connector P/N",
"value_id": null,
"value": null
},
{
"property_id": 19,
"property_name": "Connector Type",
"value_id": null,
"value": null
},
{
"property_id": 20,
"property_name": "Development P/N",
"value_id": 141,
"value": "0265BU2370"
},
{
"property_id": 21,
"property_name": "Function Dimension",
"value_id": 142,
"value": "3"
},
{
"property_id": 22,
"property_name": "IC Angle in Deg",
"value_id": 143,
"value": "-90"
},
{
"property_id": 23,
"property_name": "Marking",
"value_id": null,
"value": null
},
{
"property_id": 24,
"property_name": "Offer drawing",
"value_id": 145,
"value": "0265AU2370"
},
{
"property_id": 25,
"property_name": "O-ring P/N",
"value_id": null,
"value": null
},
{
"property_id": 26,
"property_name": "Pitch",
"value_id": 166,
"value": "14"
},
{
"property_id": 27,
"property_name": "Project category",
"value_id": null,
"value": null
},
{
"property_id": 28,
"property_name": "Protocol",
"value_id": 170,
"value": "i"
},
{
"property_id": 29,
"property_name": "Reading Dimension",
"value_id": 173,
"value": "36.5"
},
{
"property_id": 30,
"property_name": "Reading type",
"value_id": 185,
"value": "Side Read"
},
{
"property_id": 31,
"property_name": "Recommended Installation Bore Ã?",
"value_id": 191,
"value": "10"
},
{
"property_id": 32,
"property_name": "Target wheel",
"value_id": 193,
"value": "Multipole encoder"
},
{
"property_id": 33,
"property_name": "Used punch grid holder",
"value_id": 194,
"value": "F00C1F8441"
}
]
}
],
"document_numbers": [],
"target_markets": [],
"hierarchy_information": {
"child_products": []
}
} '''
need to parse this json sample into tables
The code above can get only the info under general into the table

But the child details like partnumbers and its properities are not getting parsed


You have not asked a question or provided a [MRE] with either: details of the JSON input to the query; the issues/errors with the query; or the expected output for that sample input. How do you expect us to help you if we do not know what the problem is?

JSON_TABLE (json_sample) should be JSON_TABLE (json_sample, fiddle

Need to pasre a json samp,e query coming from HTTP response into tables.

[Edit] your question and include a [MRE] with a sample of the JSON you are passing into the query; details of the issues/errors with the current query; and the expected output for that sample JSON input. Just stating "Need to pasre a json samp,e query coming from HTTP response into tables." is NOT a constructive statement as it does not tell us what the JSON sample looks like or what the output should look like.

You've asked a good number of questions so far and each of them had someone investing time in it. Consider accepting the answers to your questions, that is how stack overflow works and that is how you show appreciation for the people helping you.

You are nesting paths when you should not as they are not children of $.general:
select JT.*
FROM   JSON_TABLE ('{
  "general": {
    "product_key": "136587",
    "group_subtype_id": 1,
    "group_subtype_name": "Wheel Speed Sensor",
    "variant_id": 2,
    "variant_name": "DF11",
    "rb_customer_id": 16732
  },
  "partnumbers": [
    {
       "partnumber": "0265009953",
       "pn_type": "Series OEM",
       "mat_status": "40 - Valid",
       "properties": [
          { "property_id": 4, "property_name": "ASIC P/N", "value_id": 27, "value": "8905509055" },
          { "property_id": 5, "property_name": "ASIC type", "value_id": 56, "value": "TLE4942" },
          { "property_id": 6, "property_name": "Axle", "value_id": 64, "value": "Front" },
          { "property_id": 7, "property_name": "Base Type - Development P/N", "value_id": null, "value": null },
          { "property_id": 8, "property_name": "Base Type - Released P/N", "value_id": 73, "value": "F00C1B0037" },
          { "property_id": 9, "property_name": "Bracket assembly @ Bosch", "value_id": null, "value": null },
          { "property_id": 10, "property_name": "Bulk cable P/N", "value_id": null, "value": null },
          { "property_id": 11, "property_name": "Cable assembly P/N1", "value_id": null, "value": null },
          { "property_id": 12, "property_name": "Cable assembly P/N2", "value_id": null, "value": null },
          { "property_id": 13, "property_name": "Cable assembly P/N3", "value_id": null, "value": null },
          { "property_id": 14, "property_name": "Cable Length in mm", "value_id": null, "value": null },
          { "property_id": 15, "property_name": "Cable/Connector Outlet in Deg", "value_id": 110, "value": "Axial" },
          { "property_id": 16, "property_name": "Character", "value_id": 136, "value": "Crimped" },
          { "property_id": 17, "property_name": "Clip assembly Bosch", "value_id": null, "value": null },
          { "property_id": 18, "property_name": "Connector P/N", "value_id": null, "value": null },
          { "property_id": 19, "property_name": "Connector Type", "value_id": null, "value": null },
          { "property_id": 20, "property_name": "Development P/N", "value_id": 141, "value": "0265BU2370" },
          { "property_id": 21, "property_name": "Function Dimension", "value_id": 142, "value": "3" },
          { "property_id": 22, "property_name": "IC Angle in Deg", "value_id": 143, "value": "-90" },
          { "property_id": 23, "property_name": "Marking", "value_id": null, "value": null },
          { "property_id": 24, "property_name": "Offer drawing", "value_id": 145, "value": "0265AU2370" },
          { "property_id": 25, "property_name": "O-ring P/N", "value_id": null, "value": null },
          { "property_id": 26, "property_name": "Pitch", "value_id": 166, "value": "14" },
          { "property_id": 27, "property_name": "Project category", "value_id": null, "value": null },
          { "property_id": 28, "property_name": "Protocol", "value_id": 170, "value": "i" },
          { "property_id": 29, "property_name": "Reading Dimension", "value_id": 173, "value": "36.5" },
          { "property_id": 30, "property_name": "Reading type", "value_id": 185, "value": "Side Read" },
          { "property_id": 31, "property_name": "Recommended Installation Bore Ã?", "value_id": 191, "value": "10" },
          { "property_id": 32, "property_name": "Target wheel", "value_id": 193, "value": "Multipole encoder" },
          { "property_id": 33, "property_name": "Used punch grid holder", "value_id": 194, "value": "F00C1F8441" }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "document_numbers": [],
    "target_markets": [],
    "hierarchy_information": { "child_products": [] }
  }',
    '$'
    COLUMNS (
      product_key NUMBER PATH '$.general.product_key',
      group_subtype_id NUMBER PATH '$.general.group_subtype_id',
      group_subtype_name VARCHAR2 ( 100 ) PATH '$.general.group_subtype_name',
      variant_id NUMBER PATH '$.general.variant_id',
      variant_name VARCHAR2 ( 100 ) PATH '$.general.variant_name',
      rb_customer_id NUMBER PATH '$.general.rb_customer_id',
      NESTED PATH '$.partnumbers[*]' COLUMNS (
        partnumber VARCHAR2 ( 100 ) PATH '$.partnumber',
        pn_type VARCHAR2 ( 100 ) PATH '$.pn_type',
        mat_status VARCHAR2 ( 100 ) PATH '$.mat_status',
        base_wire_esd VARCHAR2 ( 10 ) PATH '$.properties[0].value',
        pressure VARCHAR2 ( 10 ) PATH '$.properties[1].value'
      ),
      NESTED PATH '$.document_numbers[*]' COLUMNS (
        document_number VARCHAR2 ( 100 ) PATH '$.document_number',
        document_verion NUMBER PATH '$.document_verion',
        document_type VARCHAR2 ( 100 ) PATH '$.document_type'
      ),
      NESTED PATH '$.target_markets[*]' COLUMNS (
        country_name VARCHAR2 ( 100 ) PATH '$.country_name',
        iso_code VARCHAR2 ( 10 ) PATH '$.iso_code',
        NESTED PATH '$.hierarchy_information[*]' COLUMNS (
          child_product NUMBER PATH '$'
        )
      )
    )
) jt

Outputs:



PRODUCT_KEY
GROUP_SUBTYPE_ID
GROUP_SUBTYPE_NAME
VARIANT_ID
VARIANT_NAME
RB_CUSTOMER_ID
PARTNUMBER
PN_TYPE
MAT_STATUS
BASE_WIRE_ESD
PRESSURE
DOCUMENT_NUMBER
DOCUMENT_VERION
DOCUMENT_TYPE
COUNTRY_NAME
ISO_CODE
CHILD_PRODUCT




136587
1
Wheel Speed Sensor
2
DF11
16732
0265009953
Series OEM
40 - Valid
8905509055
TLE4942
null
null
null
null
null
null



fiddle
